# SMPP connection lost before response

Tags: smpp

I've just read the SMPP Protocol V3.4 (issue 1.2)

For each request, there must be a corresponding response. (except ALERT_NOTIFICATION).

But it's not explain what happen, if the connection is lost (broken, closed) before the response was received.

```
ESME send BIND request to SMSC
ESME receive BIND response from SMSC

ESME send DATA_SM request to SMSC
** connection is lost **
```

SMSC have the response, but can't forward to ESME

```
ESME send BIND request to SMSC
ESMS receive BIND response from SMSC
```

I see 2 possibilities
a°) The SMSC will now send the DATA_SM response
b°) the DATA_SM response will be lost for ever?

If the DATA_SM response is lost, maybe the ESME will resend the DATA_SM and the end customer will receive 2 DATA_SM.

If the DATA_SM response is resend, it might have a sequence number mismatch ?

Answer (score 0):

Sequence number is a state for a current bound connection, if it drops then any _resp pdu will be dropped because their related sequence numbers on the ESME has been dropped with the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get a DATA_SM_RESP on a new bind. For one, because sequence numbers are only unique with regards to a particular session.

It is probably operator (SMSC) specific how to handle situations where the connection gets lost before they are able to send a RESP PDU, I would imagine they would possibly ignore the message.

If you are using it as an alternative to a SUBMIT_SM and have set the registered_delivery flag, you can use the delivery receipts to check the status of your message.